# How Can I Pass Params between Tabs in react-navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a case,
i got a remote notification in payload i have some data I want to pass to a specific screen.

Now

in home screen, I add a listener to listen when notification oped to get the payload well?

now in the payload itself, I got a name to tell me where should i navigate

Like this

```
username: "oliver"
screenType: "new_chat"
user_id: 21
```

Now as i say before i have listener when opened notification i check for screenType to decide where i navigate

```
const onOpened = (openResult) => {
    let {
      screenType,
      username,
      user_id,
    } = openResult.notification.payload?.additionalData;

    switch (screenType) {
     ....
      case 'new_chat':
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigation.navigate('Messages', {
            screen: 'MessagesListScreen',
            params: {
              from: 'notification',
              userIDWithoutPrefix: user_id,
              userSender: username,
            },
          });
        }, 2000);
        break;
      ....
      default:
        break;
    }
 };
```

When i open the notification its navigate me to `MessagesListScreen` and it navigates me well

but when i log the params I got `undefined`!

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('hey focus', route); // key,name well but params undefined
      
      if (fromScreen === 'notification') {
        console.log('yes if here');
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigation.navigate('ChatScreen', {
            userIDWithoutPrefix: userIDWithoutPrefix,
            userSender: userSender,
          });
        }, 500);
      } else {
        console.log('No go out', route.params); // undefined 
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

Does anyone have an explanation to this case?